# how to display different data sequentially date of status 1 first in sql server

Tags: sql-server

how to display different data sequentially date of status 1 first

result like this image

[image: Results]

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you maybe clarify a littl bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First creating the test data:

```
DECLARE @mydate TABLE
(
    date_time DATETIME,
    statusid int
)

INSERT INTO @mydate
( date_time, statusid )
VALUES
('02/25/2015 12:09:00', 0),
('02/25/2015 12:10:00', 0),
('02/25/2015 12:11:00', 0),
('02/25/2015 12:12:00', 1),
('02/25/2015 12:13:00', 1),
('02/25/2015 12:14:00', 0),
('02/25/2015 12:15:00', 0),
('02/25/2015 12:16:00', 1),
('02/25/2015 12:17:00', 1),
('02/25/2015 12:18:00', 1),
('02/25/2015 12:19:00', 1),
('02/25/2015 12:20:00', 0),
('02/25/2015 12:21:00', 0);
```

Lets find out what status is before each record

```
; WITH StatusRecs AS
(
    SELECT 
        m.date_time, 
        m.statusid, 
        LAG(m.statusid) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) AS prev_status
    FROM @mydate m
)
```

Now going to pull all of the status 1 records that are different from the prev status to find the beginning of each set, we are also going to pull the date of the next status = 1 record in next_start_date

```
,StartStatus AS
(
    SELECT 
        s.date_time, 
        s.statusid, 
        LEAD(s.date_time) OVER (ORDER BY s.date_time) AS next_start_date 
    FROM StatusRecs s
    WHERE s.statusid != ISNULL(s.prev_status, -1)
    AND s.statusid = 1
)
```

Now lets pull it all together to get the last 0 status record before the next status 1 record

```
,MyRecs AS
(
    SELECT * FROM StartStatus ss
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 sr.date_time AS date_time2, sr.statusid AS statusid2 
        FROM StatusRecs sr
        WHERE sr.date_time > ss.date_time 
        AND (sr.date_time < ss.next_start_date OR ss.next_start_date IS NULL)
        ORDER BY sr.date_time DESC
    ) m
)
```

Now we format and output the table

```
SELECT m.date_time, m.statusid, m.date_time2, m.statusid2, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, m.date_time, m.date_time2) AS duration  FROM MyRecs m

date_time   statusid    date_time2  statusid2   duration
2015-02-25 12:12:00.000 1   2015-02-25 12:15:00.000 0   3
2015-02-25 12:16:00.000 1   2015-02-25 12:21:00.000 0   5
```

Comment: thank you very much for helping , really successful :)

Answer (score -1):

this is an ugly example due to all the table read on the CTE but it might help in some way.. didn't have a SQLfiddle to test it out... try set one up for your questions, always helps.

```
with myTableNumbered (myOrder,date_time,status) AS (
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_time) myOrder,
    date_time,
    status
from myTable
)
select
    m.date_time,
    m.status,
    next.date_time datetime_2,
    next.status status2,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),datediff(minute,m.date_time,next.date_time))+'minut'duration
from myTableNumbered m
OUTER APPLY (
    select TOP 1
        next.date_time,
        next.status
    from myTableNumbered next
    where
        next.myOrder > m.myOrder and
        next.status = 0 and
        ISNULL((select status from myTableNumbered prev where prev.myOrder-1 = next.myOrder),1) = 1
    order by next.date_time asc
) next
where
    m.status = 1 and
    ISNULL((select status from myTableNumbered prev where prev.myOrder+1 = m.myOrder),0) = 0
```

Comment: thank you very much for helping , really successful :)