# how to split the data each for a total sum of 100 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

how to split the data each for a total sum of 100 
I should insert data based on dates that have a total value of 100
sample:
http://prntscr.com/6ak0ji

Comment: Please clarify your question, this is very unclear.

Comment: of the total number of 500 ,
I want to split the 5 rows in sql .
each row has a value of 100

Comment: It would be much better if you could include sample data in the OP as text, instead of adding it as a screenshot using an external link.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide your table definitions, sample data, the output you'd like to obtain from that data, and show the SQL you've tried to write to produce that output that didn't work. All of the necessary information should be here, **in text format**, so that it's available for future readers. Information in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor or  SSMS to use for testing, and your vague description of what you're asking isn't clear.

Comment: I apologize if my question is not clear ,
I do not know whether in sql could do as the external link image

Comment: Will you value of 500 will be same always? and how you have managed different values of date_time from one date_time?

Comment: previously I have data in question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726127/how-to-display-different-data-sequentially-date-of-status-1-first-in-sql-server

and I want to separate each time sum ( duration ) = 100 on a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you , I have found the answer myself . may be able to help others

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_event_with_location] (
  [event_id] bigint NOT NULL,
  [vehicle_id] int NULL,
  [position_id] bigint NULL,
  [date_time] datetime NULL,
  [event_type] smallint NULL,
  [object_id] int NULL,
  [x] int NULL,
  [y] int NULL,
  [duration] int NULL,
  [description] varchar(250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [speed] int NULL,
  [speed_limit] int NULL,
  [location_id] int NULL,
  [odometer] int NULL,
  [trip_odometer] int NULL,
  [street_name] nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [location_name] nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [kecamatan] nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [kabupaten] nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [vehicle_name] varchar(30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [geofence_code] varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [geofence_name] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [geofence_type] varchar(30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [check_point_name] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [site_name] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [site_code] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [site_type] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [route_name] varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [route_code] varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [event_type_desc] varchar(30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [driver_name] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [engine] bit NULL,
  [stop_time_limit] int NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [tmp_event_with_location_pk_tmp_event_with_location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([event_id])
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[drum_duration] (
  [drum_id] int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [member_id] int NULL,
  [vehicle_id] int NULL,
  [vehicle_number] varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [alert_limit] int NULL,
  [alert_email] varchar(30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [sensor_start_date] datetime NULL,
  [drum_date] datetime NULL,
  [duration] int NULL,
  [total_duration] int NULL,
  [create_date] datetime NULL,
  [create_by] int NULL,
  [note] varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([drum_id])
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Aprocedure7
AS
BEGIN


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
/*
table to test
*/  
DECLARE @tmp_drum table
(
  vehicle_id int ,
  alert_limit int,
  drum_date datetime ,
  from_date datetime ,
  last_drum_date datetime ,
  total_duration int,
  duration int ,
  note varchar (100)

)
insert @tmp_drum(vehicle_id , alert_limit,drum_date,from_date,total_duration )
        select dd.vehicle_id,dd.alert_limit, dd.drum_date,from_date= case when dd.drum_date is null then dd.sensor_start_date 
        else dd.drum_date end,
        dd.total_duration
        from drum_duration dd

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
get data
*/     
DECLARE @tmp_table1 TABLE
( 
  vehicle_id int, 
  date_time datetime, 
  event_type int, 
  alert_limit int,
  drum_date datetime,
  myOrder int  
) 
insert @tmp_table1( vehicle_id  ,date_time ,event_type ,alert_limit,drum_date,myOrder )               
        select b.vehicle_id, b.date_time, b.event_type, d.alert_limit,d.drum_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.date_time) myOrder
        from tmp_event_with_location b
        inner join @tmp_drum d on  d.vehicle_id =b.vehicle_id
        where b.date_time >=d.from_date  
        and b.engine=1  and b.event_type in(68,69)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
get the duration of the date
*/  

DECLARE @tmp_table2 TABLE
( 
  vehicle_id int, 
  date_time datetime, 
  event_type int, 
  datetime_2 datetime,
  event_type2 int,
  alert_limit int,
  drum_date datetime,
  duration int --,
 -- runing_total int 
)  
insert @tmp_table2 (  vehicle_id , date_time , event_type , datetime_2 ,
        event_type2, alert_limit,drum_date, duration  )                     
      select 
          m.vehicle_id,          
          m.date_time, 
          m.event_type,
          next.date_time as datetime_2, 
          next.event_type as event_type2,
          m.alert_limit,
          m.drum_date,
          convert(int,datediff(minute,m.date_time,next.date_time))as duration--sum row by date
                -- sum(convert(int,datediff(minute,m.date_time,next.date_time))) over(order by m.date_time rows between unbounded preceding and current row)  AS runing_total 
      from @tmp_table1 as m
      outer apply 
      (
        select TOP 1 next.vehicle_id, next.date_time, next.event_type
        from @tmp_table1 as next
        where next.myOrder > m.myOrder and next.event_type = 68 and isnull((select event_type from @tmp_table1 prev where prev.myOrder +1 = next.myOrder),69) = 69
        order by   next.date_time asc 
      ) as next
        where m.event_type = 69 and ISNULL((select event_type from @tmp_table1 prev where prev.myOrder+1 = m.myOrder),68) = 68                     
        and next.vehicle_id =m.vehicle_id   

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
/*
get the sum of the duration of the next column
*/         
DECLARE @tmp_table3 TABLE
( 
  vehicle_id int, 
  date_time datetime, 
  event_type int, 
  datetime_2 datetime,
  event_type2 int,
  alert_limit int,
  drum_date datetime,
  duration int ,
  runing_total int 
)  
insert @tmp_table3 (  vehicle_id , date_time ,  event_type , datetime_2 , event_type2,  alert_limit,drum_date, duration, runing_total  )                     
    select  
      n.vehicle_id, 
      n.date_time, 
      n.event_type,
      n.datetime_2, 
      n.event_type2,
      n.alert_limit,
      n.drum_date,
      n.duration,
      (select cast(sum(duration) as char(50))  from @tmp_table2
        where datetime_2 <=n.datetime_2 and  vehicle_id =n.vehicle_id) as runing_total -- ? sum duration  nex row
       from @tmp_table2 as n
       group by   
      n.vehicle_id, 
      n.date_time, 
      n.event_type,
      n.datetime_2, 
      n.event_type2,
      n.alert_limit,
      n.drum_date,
      n.duration

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
main cursor
*/

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE  @c_vehicle_id int , @c_datetime_2 datetime,@alert_limit int, @c_runing_total int
DECLARE CURSOR_RUN  CURSOR FOR
    select  t2.vehicle_id,t2.datetime_2, t2.alert_limit ,t2.runing_total 
    from @tmp_table3 as t2  
    order by t2.vehicle_id,t2.datetime_2

OPEN CURSOR_RUN
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_RUN INTO @c_vehicle_id , @c_datetime_2 ,@alert_limit, @c_runing_total   
  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    BEGIN
     print @c_vehicle_id    
      IF(@c_runing_total<=@alert_limit)
        BEGIN
            update @tmp_drum set 
            last_drum_date= @c_datetime_2,
            duration =@c_runing_total , 
            --total_duration= total_duration +  @c_runing_total ,
            note= case when  @c_runing_total <= alert_limit then '-' else 'its duration exceeds the specified limit alerts'end                           
            where vehicle_id =@c_vehicle_id
            and @c_runing_total<=@alert_limit 
            and drum_date is not null --? calculated from the date of drum_date and do not exceed the limit alerts
        END            
      ELSE   
        BEGIN
            update @tmp_drum set 
            last_drum_date= @c_datetime_2,
            duration =@c_runing_total , 
            --total_duration= total_duration +  @c_runing_total ,
            note= case when  @c_runing_total <= alert_limit then '-' else 'counted from the start of pairs of sensors'end                            
            where vehicle_id =@c_vehicle_id
            and @c_runing_total>=@alert_limit --
            and drum_date is null --? sensors installed from the beginning and over the limit alerts
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_RUN INTO @c_vehicle_id , @c_datetime_2 ,@alert_limit, @c_runing_total
  END
CLOSE CURSOR_RUN
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_RUN
SET NOCOUNT OFF

select * from @tmp_table3
select * from @tmp_drum
END
```